# Why can Stan Laurel use his thumb as a lighter in Way Out West?

Tags: plot-explanation, laurel-and-hardy, way-out-west

Why can Stan Laurel use his thumb as a lighter in Way Out West?

I know it's slapstick comedy but it just seems a bit random.

Answer (score 7):

[**TV Tropes** - Finger Snap Lighter](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FingerSnapLighter):

> **One fun way of [Playing with Fire](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlayingWithFire) is to [coolly light your cigarette, cigar or pipe](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CouldntFindALighter) with a finger snap in an extravagant show of [Mundane Utility](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MundaneUtility)**.
>
> [...]
>
> Done by ***Laurel and Hardy*** in [**Way Out West**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029747/) *(1937; probably the [Trope Maker](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TropeMakers))*.
>
> - *Stan* ignites his thumb as if it were a cigarette lighter several times; each time, *Ollie* stares in disbelief and tries to copy him. And eventually it works for *Ollie*, who reacts with horrified alarm.

[[**Watch Clip on YouTube**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDrYVzb5KAU#t=00m19s)]